# Assign document element to global variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to assign document elements to global variables so that I am able to use these elements everywhere in my code.

**My code:**

```
// document elements
var drop = null;
var status = null;
var show = null;

function process (drop, status, show) {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
        // init elements
        drop = document.getElementById(drop);
        status = document.getElementById(status);
        show = document.getElementById(show);
    }

    // init event handlers
    drop.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
}

function handleDrop (evt) {
    // do something
}
```

The problem is I can't do anything with the document elements using the global variables in the function handleDrop while in the function process everything works as it should...

EDIT: For example, I can read the content of the element show (show.innerHTML) in the function process but not in the function handleDrop.

Comment: How do you know that you "can't do anything" with the variables?  Are you 100% sure that they're actually set by the "process" function?

Comment: It's weird, but... please define `everything works as it should`. From what I see, it's clearly not working: you work with local (= taken from parameters) variables all the way in `process` function.

Comment: What I mean by everything works as it should is that for example I can read the content of the element show (show.innerHTML) in the fucntion process but not in the function handleDrop. I'll edit my question.

Comment: you can do this, but you'll need to update your global variables to point to the elements after they have loaded.

Comment: Your "handler" function - is it *really* declared like that, right after "process"?

Comment: @Pointy Yes it is. I'm rather new to JavaScript so if I'm doing something wrong please let me know :).

Comment: @PhilippeMaes  the reason I ask is that if your code really looks exactly like that, there's no way you'd have the problem.  If the two functions and the variables are all declared in the same context - either globally, or inside a "load" or "ready" handler - then both functions would have equivalent access to the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all these `drop`, `status`... variables within `process` function are the local ones - they refer to its arguments, and not the variables defined earlier.

If these were defined at the outer-most level (i.e., not within any function's body), you can access (and alter) them like this:

```
window.drop = document.getElementById(drop);
window.status = document.getElementById(status);
window.show = document.getElementById(show);
```

But I'd actually suggest another way: using *separate* names for params and 'closured-over' variables. Like this:

```
function process(dropId, statusId, showId) {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
        // init elements
        drop = document.getElementById(dropId);
        status = document.getElementById(statusId);
        show = document.getElementById(showId);
    }
}
```

Both ways allow you to address these variables within `handleDrop` function; the latter one is obviously superior, because you are not restricted with what scope to choose.

Comment: Personally I prefer the explicit reference to 'window', this kinda tells me "I know I shouldn't use globals, but I did this intentionally".

Comment: In his post however the `var` declaration is clearly **outside** the function. They're not local variables.

Comment: @Pointy: that doesn't matter.. declaring an argument with the same name implies a new scope..

Comment: @Pointy Outside the functions mentioned - yes. Outside _any_ function - are you really sure with that?

Comment: @Evert Consider, for example, the code shown as part of omnipresent `(function() { ... })()` modularizing block. You either have to use `window` all the time, or just use the fact that JS has closures; I'd definitely choose the latter. )

Comment: @raina77ow no, but if the code really looks like that and "handler" is declared right after "process" then it wouldn't matter.  However, I suspect you're right and that the code as posted is not actually what the OP was working with.